# Is there a way to watch a .git folder, and update my git log whenever it changes?

Tags: git, bash, unix, zsh, fswatch

I have been trying to create an automatically updating `git log --graph --no-pager`. I made some strides using `fswatch` but I ran into the issue of my git history being actually bigger than my screen can display. I tried adding `` | head -n $((`tput lines` - 1)) `` but the output is still overflowing because of line wrapping. I then tried using `tput rmam` in order to disable wrapping, but now I can't usually see where `HEAD` points to.

Anyone could help me? Ideally, I'd like to remove `--no-pager`, but I don't know how to make that work with `fswatch`. Here is what I have so far:

```
function gwatch() {
  tput rmam
  location=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
  clear;
  git --no-pager graph --color | head -n $((`tput lines` - 1));
  tput smam

  fswatch -or $location/.git | while read MODFILE
  do
    tput rmam
    clear;
    git --no-pager graph --color | head -n $((`tput lines` - 1));
    tput smam
  done
}
```

Comment: cron job. `0 * * * * cd /path/to/repo; git log --graph --no-pager > logfile` Runs hourly.

Comment: ...What? I don't understand how a cron job would be helpful here...

Comment: Why bother setting up a watcher when you could just blindly log it every hour?

Comment: ...That's just not what I asked for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a less elegant solution than yours but simple: using *watch*.

```
watch -n 1  "sh -c 'git log | head -n $(tput lines)'"
```

*watch* will do the paging for you but you won't be able to browse the log.

But if you want that, you can use the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

gitwatch()
{
    while true; do
        sleep 3
        fswatch -xr $location/.git/objects | while read events; do
            if echo $events | grep -q Created; then
                pid=$(pgrep -t $(ps -o tty= -p $$) $PAGER)
                kill $pid
                break
            fi
        done
    done
}

location=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)

gitwatch &

while true; do
    git log
done
```

I put a *sleep* because we have multiple creations of files in one modification in *git*. This code needs a better solution to catch a modification in *git* than watching all git objects!

Instead of `-x` and then `grep` with *Created*, you can use `-o --event=Created`. However, this approach is less responsive and seems not to work all the time.

Comment: That's what the -o flag does for `fswatch`! It replaces multiple notifications with just one with a count of how many changes occurred! Let me give this a shot, and I'll let you know how that went! :)

Comment: May I ask how does the `pid` line work? It seems like just a bunch arcane incantations to me. Lol

Comment: With `-o` it is less responsive but I will add it in my answer. The line with `pid` try to find the pid of the process PAGER in the same tty. In this context, the `tty` command does not work.